# Outnumbering in Unknown

Tags: balance

The Outnumbering rule in Unknown states:

> If the survivors outnumber the enemies, enemy damage is reduced by 1 for every 2 excess survivors

We're reading this two different ways:

- To reduce the damage of N enemies to zero, you need N*3 survivors
- Damage from each enemy is treated separately, so for N enemies, you need N+2 survivors

The first ruling seems more correct, but we were convinced to use the second ruling last time we played. The outnumbering example in the rules only has one monster, so it isn't helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read the rule as enemies (plural) being outnumbered leads to an enemy (singular) having it's damage reduced.  So each enemy has it damages reduced the same amount by being outnumbered.  I would calculate the reduction in damage as follow, with S being survivors and E enemies.

`Damage reduction = (S-E)/2`

So if a enemies did 3 damage and you wanted to reduce it to 0 you'd need to outnumber the the group by 6.